# Bootstrap v2.3.1 is not working for tabs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I am having **Bootstrap version 2.3.1** and In that tabs are not working . It can be solved if I am upgraded to new version. But if I upgraded my bootstrap version all the previous view changing and navbar is also not working. So I want to stay in 2.3.1 version and I want to create tabs in my website.Please Help me in this thanks in advance.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>  
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" />  

    /*!
  * Bootstrap v2.3.1
  *
  * Copyright 2012 Twitter, Inc
  * Licensed under the Apache License v2.0
  * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  *
  * Designed and built with all the love in the world @twitter by @mdo and @fat.
```

Comment: where is HTML/CSS/JS code?

Answer (score 0):

Here the following  fiddle link i done the same tabs with bootstrap 2.3 v check it out [Working fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hahkarthick/279o67pz/)

***Suggestion***: **I have faced same problem in one design use the following link to convert your bootstrap version** & its free to use

[Bootstrap version conversion tool](http://code.divshot.com/bootstrap3_upgrader/)

```css
@import "//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css";

.tab:not(:target) {
  display: none;
}

.tab:last-child {
  display: block;
}

.tab:target ~ .tab:last-child {
  display: none;
}

.tabs {
  width: 30em;
  margin: 6.5em auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <div id="tab3" class="tab">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li><a href="#tab1">Description</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab2">How it works</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="#tab3">Drawbacks</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
      <li>Tab bar should be duplicated on each tab.</li>
      <li>Initially shown tab has to be the last.</li>
      <li>In IE &lt; 9 all tabs are shown.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="tab2" class="tab">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li><a href="#tab1">Description</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="#tab2">How it works</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab3">Drawbacks</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ol>
      <li>Show only the last tab.</li>
      <li>If <code>:target</code> matches a tab, show it and hide all following siblings.</li>
    </ol>
  </div>

  <div id="tab1" class="tab">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Description</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab2">How it works</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab3">Drawbacks</a></li>
    </ul>

    <p>The idea is to use <code>:target</code> pseudoclass to show tabs, use anchors with fragment identifiers to switch between them.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It was applying to other classes also and I don't want to apply it

Comment: simple add a new class and try it out @mohansriramakrishnaP

Comment: already I have some classes previously thing is if I imported new version bootstrap file all the previous view is changing and I don't want that to happen

Comment: OK,if you could  share your code to help you .@mohansriramakrishnaP